# InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425: Trailing data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I just recently migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL.
I noticed I kept getting this error

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
Trailing data
```

Then, I did a global search for `Carbon::` in my application. I found 47 matches across 15 files.

How do I fix this errors without having to modify all those files ?

---

I **dd()** my object this is what I got

```
Capture {#412 ▼
  #table: "captures"
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 65
    "type" => "cpe"
    "cpe_mac" => "000D6721A5EE"
    "device_mac" => null
    "created_at" => "2016-05-03 11:20:10-04"
    "updated_at" => "2016-05-03 11:20:10-04"
  ]

   ....
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL did you migrate away from? Timestamp fields have different storage values across different MySQL storage engines and WILL differ to PostgreSQL. SOURCE: I had to do a migration from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 5.5 due to circumstance and experienced the same. Turns out that 5.7 timestamps were also saving the milliseconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's exactly what you think. The issue here is that the `timestamp` column in `PostgreSQL` is actually expecting a different timestamp format which includes the `miliseconds` at the end. `'Y-m-d H:i:s.u'` as opposed to Carbon's default format and MySQL's timestamp column which is just `'Y-m-d H:i:s`. In order to fix this, tell PostgreSQL that you don't want to store the Timezone as part of your strings in your `timestamp` columns:

```
ALTER TABLE {tablename} ALTER updated_at SET DATA TYPE timestamp(0) without time zone;
```

You'll need to do this for all tables and all columns which have a timestamp.

Comment: How can I alter to my entire database ? I have about 10 tables. Please advise.

Comment: @ihue Just do them one by one. Save them as `migrations` and run `rawSQL` inside of them, this way you can still just do `php artisan migrate` in any future environments.

Comment: what should I put in my down() ? `DB::statement('ALTER TABLE cloud-securities ALTER updated_at SET DATA TYPE timestamp(0) with time zone;');` ?

Comment: @ihue Yep. Basically.

Answer (score 0):

Realise this is an old post, but I have solved this problem by creating a global scope. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#global-scopes

I then did:

$builder->addSelect(['select','cols','here',to_char(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as created_at"];

Which then means works appropriately with Laravel. As I am only reading from this DB, don't need to consider updating timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a Carbon error, it's because you probably need date in milliseconds.

```
"created_at" => "2018-04-19 07:01:19.929554"
```

You can add the following method to your (base) model.

```
public function getDateFormat()
{
     return 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
}
```

If you are using TIME WITH TIMEZONE in Postgres then the format should be:

```
Y-m-d H:i:s.uO
```